# how to define rules for arraylist in model yii 1.1?

Tags: yii, rule

i have defined a variable as an array in my model and i have defined rule for that array as :

```
public $nameList;
public function rules()
{
 array('nameList','type'=>'array','allowEmpty'=>false),
}
```

I have tried this.I am getting problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and it will work

```
public function rules()
{
 array('nameList','type','type'=>'array','allowEmpty'=>false)
}
```